# My layout refuses to be full width of the device

Tags: android, xamarin, layout, width

LinearLayout always takes up only the first left side of the screen. I would like it to be the full width of the screen.

I have tried all of the options I know, even Googled this and I think I have it correct but my LinearLayout is always half the width of the screen.
This might be a duplicate but I have tried the rest.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="#ffcccc"
      android:fillViewport="true">

     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:padding="4dp"
         android:background="#ccffcc"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           <EditText
              android:id="@+id/UserNameEditText"
              android:hint="@string/offender_name"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           <EditText
              android:hint="@string/citation_info_document_type"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           <EditText
              android:hint="@string/citation_document_number"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           <EditText
              android:hint="@string/citation_location_heading"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

     </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

I expect it to fill the screen horizontally.
If I add divider code anywhere on the screen it fills it.

I set the 2 background colors to see what showed and what did not. All I see is the light green LinearLayout.

Edit:
I removed the colors and I have checked and I have nothing in my code file that would affect the axml file.

[image: This is what the screen looks like when rendered on my emulator and my device]

Note please that this screen is a fragment, and the solution is clean, i.e. no other code except to display the fragment and build the screen.

Comment: the scrollview is what makes your linearlayout scroll, as you have it you're only supposed to be seeing the light green layout anyway.Not sure what the problem is. I ran your code and the linear layout fills the screen. can you post images of what you get and what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: also with the scrollview present, you're better off setting the layout_height of the LinearLAyout to wrap_content

Comment: You have set the layout width to match parent- maybe check the layout width of the parent? If that one is restricted to the left side of the screen, it would restrict your linear layout as well. Did you add any additional view groups that might restrict the linear layout?

Comment: I added a screenshot and I have also tried setting the LinearLayout to wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling says that its the ParentMost ScrollView that is messing with you!

Wrap it in a LinearLayout or something and it should work for you

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent/>

 <ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:fillViewport="true">...</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you but i tried that this morning and it still did not work.
I removed the android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout and changed to just EditText and that worked. 
I suspect it's something in the Material Design that is messing this up.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to something in the Android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout because if I set android:layout_width="1440px" on the ScrollView it works fine.
Also the first time I run it, it fails with no reason, even with the logs turned up, then if I run it again, it compiles fine.

Comment: Can you give me your version detials i will have to look it out myself

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.9.7
Net Framework Version 4.7.03056